# JavaScript Game Grid Tile Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid that is made from tiles. There are 10 rows, with a total of 10 tiles in a row. This totals 100 tiles in the grid.

When any tile is clicked, I would like the tiles around the clicked tile to be highlighted. The highlighted tiles should start one away from the clicked tile and spread outwards, with a maximum of 2 tiles away from the clicked tile.

So far I have managed to get the tiles to the top, right, bottom and left to be highlighted, however I am still missing the tiles around these. The shape should form a diamond around the clicked tile.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6vbzjz0/)

The solution has to be extensible to allow for bigger grids and bigger move distances of tiles.

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
var Move = function () {

    var that = this;

    this.grid = {
        width: 10,
        height: 10
    };

    this.showMoveableTiles = function () {
        var movableTiles = 2;
        var row = $(this).data('row');
        var tile = $(this).data('tile');

        $('.tile').removeClass('moveable');

        // Left
        $(this).prevAll('[data-row="' + row + '"]:lt(' + movableTiles + ')').addClass('moveable');

        // Right
        $(this).nextAll('[data-row="' + row + '"]:lt(' + movableTiles + ')').addClass('moveable');

        for (var i = 1; i <= movableTiles; i++) {
            // Top
            $('[data-row="' + (row - i) + '"][data-tile="' + tile + '"]').addClass('moveable');

            // Bottom
            $('[data-row="' + (row + i) + '"][data-tile="' + tile + '"]').addClass('moveable');
        }
    };

};

var move = new Move();

$(document).on('mousedown', '.tile', move.showMoveableTiles);
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter the tiles which have desired distance (and exclude clicked tile) like this

```
 $('#grid .tile').filter(function(){
            return Math.abs($(this).data('row') - row) <= movableTiles && Math.abs($(this).data('tile') - tile) <= movableTiles && !($(this).data('row') == row && $(this).data('tile') == tile)
 }).addClass('moveable');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z6vbzjz0/2/

**EDIT**
Filtering according to your distance-definition (Manhatten-Distance) should be done like this:

```
 $('#grid .tile').filter(function(){
            return ( Math.abs($(this).data('row') - row) +  Math.abs($(this).data('tile') - tile) )<= movableTiles && !($(this).data('row') == row && $(this).data('tile') == tile)
        }).addClass('moveable');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z6vbzjz0/4/

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am after. Only tiles that are 2 or less tiles away from the clicked tile should be highlighted.

Comment: ah so you define distance as edge-crossing?

Comment: Yes. The final shape would look something like a diamond. Something [like this](http://i.imgur.com/59EpZDP.png).

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A quick implementation would be to add these to your `showMoveableTiles` function:

```
        //Top Left
         $('[data-row="' + (row - 1) + '"][data-tile="' + (tile -1) + '"]').addClass('moveable');
        //Bottom Left
         $('[data-row="' + (row + 1) + '"][data-tile="' + (tile -1) + '"]').addClass('moveable');
        //Top Right
         $('[data-row="' + (row - 1) + '"][data-tile="' + (tile + 1) + '"]').addClass('moveable');
        //Bottom Right
         $('[data-row="' + (row + 1) + '"][data-tile="' + (tile + 1) + '"]').addClass('moveable');
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z6vbzjz0/3/

Add these lines into your `showMoveableTiles` function:

```
        //top corners
        $('[data-row=' + (row - 1) + '][data-tile=' + (tile - 1) + ']').addClass('moveable');
        $('[data-row=' + (row - 1) + '][data-tile=' + (tile + 1) + ']').addClass('moveable');
        //bottom corners
        $('[data-row=' + (row + 1) + '][data-tile=' + (tile - 1) + ']').addClass('moveable');
        $('[data-row=' + (row + 1) + '][data-tile=' + (tile + 1) + ']').addClass('moveable');
```

This basically just looks at the current tile and row and adds or subtracts in the jquery selector to add the `moveable` class to the tiles at either corner.

Here it is again:

```js
var Move = function () {

    var that = this;

    this.grid = {
        width: 10,
        height: 10
    };

    this.showMoveableTiles = function () {
        var movableTiles = 2;
        var row = $(this).data('row');
        var tile = $(this).data('tile');

        $('.tile').removeClass('moveable');

        // Left
        $(this).prevAll('[data-row="' + row + '"]:lt(' + movableTiles + ')').addClass('moveable');

        // Right
        $(this).nextAll('[data-row="' + row + '"]:lt(' + movableTiles + ')').addClass('moveable');
        
        for (var i = 1; i <= movableTiles; i++) {
            // Top
            $('[data-row="' + (row - i) + '"][data-tile="' + tile + '"]').addClass('moveable');

            // Bottom
            $('[data-row="' + (row + i) + '"][data-tile="' + tile + '"]').addClass('moveable');
        }
        
        //top corners
        $('[data-row=' + (row - 1) + '][data-tile=' + (tile - 1) + ']').addClass('moveable');
        $('[data-row=' + (row - 1) + '][data-tile=' + (tile + 1) + ']').addClass('moveable');
        //bottom corners
        $('[data-row=' + (row + 1) + '][data-tile=' + (tile - 1) + ']').addClass('moveable');
        $('[data-row=' + (row + 1) + '][data-tile=' + (tile + 1) + ']').addClass('moveable');
    };

};

var makeGrid = function (width, height) {
    var tiles = '';

    for (var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (var tile = 1; tile <= width; tile++) {
            tiles += '<div class="tile" data-tile="' + tile + '" data-row="' + (row + 1) + '"></div>';
        }
    }

    $('#grid').append(tiles);
};

var move = new Move();

makeGrid(10, 10);

$(document).on('mousedown', '.tile', move.showMoveableTiles);
```

```css
#grid {
    width: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tile {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #777;
    outline: 1px solid goldenrod;
    float: left;
}

.tile:hover {
    background-color: #999;
}

.moveable {
    background-color: #add8e6;
}

.moveable:hover {
    background-color: #c8ebf7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works for tiles up to 2 or less away from the clicked tile. This will need to be extensible for more tiles, i.e. up 3, or 4, or 5, etc.

Comment: Ah, I missed the 'extensible' part of the question.

Comment: Looks like @L. Monty has given you the solution you needed.